# Back button event not fired while keyboard is open in Android in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How to handle hardware back button pressed while keyboard is open in Xamarin Forms?The **OnBackPressed** event does not fire if the keyboard is open.Is there any way I can track the hardware back button click while the keyboard is open?

Comment: But the back button will close the keyboard, won't it? And once it is closed, the next click on the back button should fire OnBackPressed. That's how it is supposed to work on the platform.

Comment: Yes.But in my app I have an entry field with keyboard open when im typing.After clicking the hardware back button I want to force the entry field to loose focus.So i wanted to track that event. @ThomasHilbert

Answer (score 0):

> After clicking the hardware back button I want to force the entry field to loose focus.

You could override the `OnBackButtonPressed` method to track the hardware back button click, it did work even if your keyboard is open.

For example :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if (myEntry.IsFocused)
        {
            myEntry.Unfocus();
        }
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }

}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf3RL.gif).

Comment: It does not work.OnBackButtonPressed  and OnBackPressed does not get fired when keyboard is open. @York

Comment: @Debasish, it works fine on my side, could you please share a basic demo to reproduce this problem?